# Probelm in solving $\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

While solving $\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) = 0$, if I convert $\sin$ into $\cos$, I am getting answer (i.e. $\left(n + \frac{1}{4}\right)\pi$ and $\left(2n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi$. However, if I convert $\cos$ to $\sin$, I am not getting answer (i.e. $\left(\frac{1}{2} - n\right)\pi$ and $\left(\frac{n}{2} +\frac{1}4{}\right)\pi$).

Where am I wrong?

Is there any specific way to solve these equations?

Comment: When you say convert, what identity are you using to make this conversion exactly?

Comment: From cos(3x/2) to sin (pi/2 - (3x/2)) thus sin(x/2) = sin(pi/2 -(3x/2)), hence, (x/2) = [n*pi + (-1)^n {pi/2 -(3x/2)}] and from sin(x/2) to cos(pi/2 - x/2), thus cos(3x/2) = cos (pi/2 -x/2), hence, 3x/2 = [2n*pi +/- {pi/2 - x/2}]

Comment: I can't easily read that with your lack of markup, but I at least see where you were going with it now.

Answer (score 1):

If $$\cos x=\cos A\ \ \ \ (1)$$

$x=2m\pi\pm A$

$$(1)\iff\sin(\pi/2-x)=\sin(\pi/2-A)$$

Either

$$\pi/2-x=2n\pi+(\pi/2-A)\iff x=A-2n\pi\implies n=-m$$

Or

$$\pi/2-x=2m\pi+\pi-(\pi/2-A)\iff x=-2n\pi-A$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the angle sum formulas

$$
\sin(a\pm b)= \sin(a)\cos(b)\pm \cos(a)\sin(b)\hspace{4pc} \cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)\mp \sin(a)\sin(b).
$$

We will apply this to both by taking $\sin(x/2)=\sin\left (x-\frac{x}{2}\right)$ and $\cos(3x/2)=\cos\left (x+\frac{x}{2}\right )$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\sin(x/2)-\cos(3x/2)&=& \sin(x)\cos(x/2)-\cos(x)\sin(x/2)-\cos(x)\cos(x/2)+\sin(x)\sin(x/2)\\
&=& \sin(x)[\cos(x/2)+ \sin(x/2)] -\cos(x)[\cos(x/2)+\sin(x/2)]\\
&=& [\sin(x)-\cos(x)][\cos(x/2)+\sin(x/2)].
\end{eqnarray}

Setting this equal to zero now you should be able to find a solution set quite easily.  From here you can find that this breaks up into two equations: $\tan(x)=1$ and $\tan(x/2)=-1$ which gives us solutions of the form $\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi k$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi k$ respectively.  You can arrange the last of these expressions to be $-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k$

Answer (score 0):

Cosine to sine:

$$\sin(x/2)-\cos(3x/2)=0 \\
\sin(x/2) - \sin(\pi/2-3x/2)=0 \\
\sin(x/2)=\sin(\pi/2-3x/2).$$

Now you have a tricky issue: two sines can be equal when their arguments are equal up to a shift by a multiple of $2\pi$, or when the argument of one is $\pi$ minus the argument of the other up to a shift by a multiple of $2\pi$. In the first case:

$$x/2=\pi/2-3x/2 + 2n\pi \\
x=\pi/4+n\pi.$$

In the second case:

$$x/2=\pi-(\pi/2-3x/2)+2n\pi \\
x/2=\pi/2+3x/2+2n\pi \\
x=-\pi/2+2n\pi$$

where I've changed what $n$ is between the second and last line since it is still an arbitrary integer.

So both sets of solutions wind up being valid. Similar reasoning applies if you convert the sine to a cosine, in that case there is another "branch" where the argument of one is the negative of the argument of the other up to a shift by a multiple of $2\pi$. In general you can only conclude that $x=y+2n\pi$ if $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$ and also $\cos(x)=\cos(y)$.

Comment: The answer given in text book is (n+(1/4))*pi and (2n-(1/2))*pi which I have obtained by converting sin into cos. As per your calculation, I have also obtained answer matching with your first case by putting general value for sin. However, I am not able to match my answer as per second case. The answer obtained by converting cos to sin and obtaining value of 'x' does not agree with the original equation at some value of 'x'.

Comment: @AnuragGupta I had one small error and now our answers agree...can you be more clear about where you think the deviation is?

Comment: Please check answer obtained in second case. As per second step of it when 3x/2 is taken to LHS then it will become -3x/2 and adding it with x/2 will result to -x. Hence, according to me answer in second case should be x = -(2n+0.5)*pi.

Comment: @AnuragGupta Right, but $n$ is an arbitrary integer, so $-n$ is also an arbitrary integer, so by the usual abuse of notation you can replace $-2n \pi$ with just $2n\pi$ (by taking the new $n$ which is still arbitrary to be the negative of the old $n$).

Answer (score 0):

Write $\sin \frac x2=-\cos(\frac\pi2+\frac x2)$ and factorize with $\cos a+\cos b =2\cos\frac{a+b}2 \cos\frac{a-b}2$,

$$\sin\frac x2 - \cos\frac{3x}2 
= -2\cos(x+\frac\pi4)\cos(\frac x2-\frac\pi4)=0$$
which leads to the solutions

$$x= \frac\pi4+n\pi,\> -\frac{\pi}2+2n\pi$$

Comment: Please provide me the formula which you have used in this identity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I would like to ask that insted of using cos a + cos b if I use identity sin a + sin b then will we get the same result?

Comment: @AnuragGupta - you would. Note $\sin\frac x2 - \cos\frac{3x}2 = \sin\frac x2 - \sin(\frac\pi2-\frac{3x}2 )=2\sin(x-\frac\pi4)\cos(\frac x2-\frac\pi4)=0$

Comment: Thanks.. I got my answer....